# Elixir: Enum.EmptyError Passing a list to Sentient Library

Tags: enums, elixir

I am trying to do a sentiment analysis on a fiction novel by passing each sentence to the analyze function in the external library Sentient. I am repeatedly getting the following error:

```
(Enum.EmptyError) empty error
(elixir) lib/enum.ex:1590: Enum.reduce/2
(elixir) lib/enum.ex:1184: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
(sentiment) lib/sentiment.ex:23: Sentiment.analyze/1
(sentiment) lib/sentiment.ex:6: Sentiment.run/1
(stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
(elixir) lib/code.ex:168: Code.eval_string/3
```

To the best of my knowledge, I am not passing an empty string to my function. I have been using a test file that contains the following:

```
This is a test. This sentence is sad. This sentence is happy. The end.
```

This is my code:

```
defmodule Sentiment do

  def run(file) do
    file
    |> fileread
    |> analyze
    |>IO.inspect
  end

  def fileread(file) do
    file
    |> File.stream!
    |> Stream.map(&String.trim_trailing(&1))
    |> Enum.map(&String.replace(&1, ~r/[-@#$%^&*()=_+|;':",<>']/, ""))
    |> Stream.map(&String.split(&1,~r/[\p{P}\p{S}]+/, trim: true))
    |> Enum.to_list
    |> List.flatten
    |> IO.inspect
  end

  def analyze(list) do
    list
    |> Enum.map(&Sentient.analyze(&1))
    |> IO.inspect
  end

end
```

I put an IO.inspect at the end of my fileread function in order to check if there was an empty entry in the list. There is not, this is the result of my `fileread` function:

```
mix run -e 'Sentiment.run("test.txt")'
["This is a test", " This sentence is sad", " This sentence is happy",
 " The end"]
```

So, I'm really not sure why I'm getting this error. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Judging by your stack trace it looks like the `Enum.EmptyError` is raised by `Enum.map/2` and not by `&Sentient.analyze(&1)`. Are you 100% positive that `list` in `analyze/1` is the list of arrays you show in your question?

Comment: I would assume so, since I'm just calling the run function, which just pipes a file into the fileread/1 function, then pipes the result of that into analyze/1.

Comment: Which version of Elixir are you using? (I'm trying to understand the stacktrace.)

Comment: I'm running 1.3.4, thanks!

Comment: Can you try calling `Sentient.analyze()` on each of those 4 sentences manually in `iex -S mix`? Does any of them raise any error?

Comment: Please, clarify whether **`Sentient` and `SentiMent` are the different modules, or there is a typo**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in `sentient`:

```
$ mix run -e 'Sentient.analyze("This is a test")'
** (Enum.EmptyError) empty error
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1722: Enum.reduce/2
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:170: Code.eval_string/3
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:645: Enum."-each/2-lists^foreach/1-0-"/2
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:645: Enum.each/2
    (mix) lib/mix/tasks/run.ex:78: Mix.Tasks.Run.run/1
```

It looks like the author [fixed](https://github.com/dantame/sentient/commit/4f862f7d1f5bdd1aab3d7fdb602f022a3c138d63) this in the Git repo but never released it on hex.pm. With the current git version the above statement does not throw any error.

The bug was that the old version was calling `Enum.reduce/2` with an empty list, which is documented to throw that error if the list is empty. They changed that to `Enum.reduce/3` with a default accumulator value in the commit linked earlier which handles empty lists just fine.